# How do I get the absolute path of an input file in R

Tags: r

I am using Rscript to plot some figures from a given CSV file in some directory, which is not necessarily my current working directory. I can call it as follows:

```
./script.r ../some_directory/inputfile.csv
```

Now I want to output my figures in the same directory (../some_directory), but I have no idea how to do that. I tried to get the absolute path for the input file because from this I could construct the output path, but I couldn't find out how to do that.

Answer (score 69):

```
normalizePath() #Converts file paths to canonical user-understandable form
```

or

```
library(tools)
file_path_as_absolute()
```

Comment: Both `normalizePath(".")` and `file_path_as_absolute(".")` still work for me on R 3.2.3.

Comment: @Greg can you list which version(s) of R you found that this did not work on? I am about to integrate this in my program and it would be really helpful to know ahead of time, thanks.

Comment: @user5359531 great question. I'm not entirely sure but I think I was using R 3.2.3, but I did not try using MattBagg's update

Comment: `normalizePath()` is part of base R and should be safe to use in your codebase.

Answer (score 10):

*The question is very old but it still misses a working solution. So here is my answer:*

Use `normalizePath(dirname(f))`. 
The example below list all the files and directories in the current directory.

```
dir <- "."
allFiles <- list.files(dir)
for(f in allFiles){
  print(paste(normalizePath(dirname(f)), fsep = .Platform$file.sep, f, sep = "")) 
}
```

Where:

- `normalizePath(dirname(f))` gives the absolute path of the parent directory. So the individual file names should be added to the path.
- `.Platform` is used to have an OS-portable code. ([here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Platform.html))
- `file.sep` gives "the file separator used on your platform: "/" on both Unix-alikes and on Windows (but not on the former port to Classic Mac OS)." ([here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Platform.html))

---

**Warning:** This may cause some problems if not used with caution. For instance, say this is the path: `A/B/a_file` and the working directory is now set to `B`. Then the code below:

```
dir <- "B"
allFiles <- list.files(dir)
for(f in allFiles){
  print(paste(normalizePath(dirname(f)), fsep = .Platform$file.sep, f, sep = "")) 
}
```

would give:

```
> A/a_file
```

however, it should be:

```
> A/B/a_file
```

Answer (score 7):

Here the solution:

```
args = commandArgs(TRUE)

results_file = args[1]

output_path = dirname(normalizePath(results_file))
```

Comment: It seems `dirname()` only gives the path minus the current folder.  Is there something similar that would give the full path?

Answer (score 3):

`fs::path_abs()` is my preferred way. It avoids the backslashes of `normalizePath()`.

Answer (score 2):

**To get the absolute path(s) from file(s)**

Why not combine the base R function `file.path()` with the answer that @Marius gave. This appears marginally simpler, will work with a vector of files (`files`), and take care of system specific separators:

```
file.path(normalizePath(dirname(files)), files)
```

And wrapped inside a function (`abspath`):

`abspath <- function(files)file.path(normalizePath(dirname(files)), files)`

For instance:

```
> setwd("~/test")
> list.files()
[1] "file1.txt" "file2.txt"
```

And then:

```
> abspath(files)
[1] "/home/myself/test/file1.txt" "/home/myself/test/file2.txt"
```

Answer (score 1):

I see that people gave pieces of the solution, but not all of it.
I have used this:

```
outputFile = paste(normalizePath(dirname(inputFile)),"\\", "my_file.ext", sep = "")
```

Hope it helps.