# Get the full name of file in a Folder

Tags: r, windows

I am using R's `list.files()` function to get the list of all files in a folder. However currently, the complete path of that folder is quite lengthly, and R shortens this using `~` notation.

Is there any way to get the full path without use of `~`?

I am using R in Windows machine.

Any pointer will be highly appreciated.

Comment: add argument `full.names = TRUE`. For more info `?list.files`

Comment: Yes I have `full.names = TRUE` But this gives the full path. In my case since that full path is lengthy, `R` is shortening that using `~`, which I dont want

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get the absolute path of an input file in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13311180/how-do-i-get-the-absolute-path-of-an-input-file-in-r)

Answer (score 1):

`normalizePath()` will prevent the shortening of the path.

For example `normalizePath(list.files(full.names = TRUE))`

Answer (score 0):

Try `path.expand(list.files(path_to_directory, full.names = TRUE))`.

Comment: Thanks. But this is not working when R shorten a file path like `'/~$XXX.xls'`, where the actual name is `'/asXXX.xls'`

Comment: Is `normalizePath` giving the correct absolute paths? If not, is it possible that the absolute paths that you want to retrieve exceed 260 characters, usually the maximum path length on Windows?